# Is there a name for the promotional packs of tissues peculiar to Japan?

Tags: phrase-requests, word-requests

Anybody who has visited a Japanese city will have noticed that peculiar type of advertising not common elsewhere.

Packets of tissues containing some promotional offer or even quite like a calling card are ubiquitous. Is there a special term for them?

Comment: I love those tissues!  Never had to search for Kleenex when I was in Japan.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ポケットティッシュ is the generic term for those tissue packs. As far as I know, there is no one word for "ポケットティッシュ for promotion".

[Manufacturers of those tissue packs](http://dir.yahoo.co.jp/Business_and_Economy/Business_to_Business/Marketing_and_Advertising/Advertising/Promotional_Items/Pocket_Tissue/) seem to call them:

- [販促]{はんそく}用の(ポケット)ティッシュ (販促 = abbreviation for 販売促進 (sales promotion))
- [宣伝]{せんでん}用の(ポケット)ティッシュ
- プロモーション用の(ポケット)ティッシュ

**Edit:** Everyone knows those promotional tissue packs, so in general you can just say 「駅でティッシュをもらった」 and 「ティッシュ配りのアルバイト」and so on, without the risk of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

I'll probably call it 駅前で配ってるティッシュ. As in 「駅前で配ってるやつでごめんね」 (they are usually bad quality).

Comment: Oddly I usually get them from places other than in front of train stations myself. Usually on the street in entertainment districts. But I've also been given them directly by sales reps when hitchhiking or by the owner of a rider house I stayed in (-:

Comment: I do not think OP is asking how you personally call it.

Comment: I don't think Enno is alone though. I did more Googling as the answers and comments came in and saw such things mentioned.